# Can a society completely erase all memory of a predecessor culture’s collapse in only three generations?

Tags: culture, history, secret-society

Something bad happened and the world chose to cover the event up by erasing their activities.

My world believes they are survivors/refugees of a "lost civilization" such as the Khmer, and they have absolutely no living memory<sup>†</sup> or other record of what ended the world. Due to some diligent archivist, they do have vast archives of the old civilization—essentially a Library of Alexandria containing culture, science, laws, fashion, weather—which account for all activity up until the disaster. Modern society has made a best estimate of the disaster's date to be 130 years ago.

**Fast forward** to my story: Not a single physical trace of that extinct civilization has yet been discovered beyond the archive. The apocalyptic environment limits them severely; they have only yet explored a small region half the size of the Sahara - diameter of 1,500 miles. Not a building, a canal, a grave, or even a nut or a bolt has been found from the old world. The entire dead industrial civilization only exists in the written archives documenting them. All modern structures, excavations, machines, etc., have originated with this modern society or from people known to them, but some early major structures were built without records.

### Question

How to completely erase an industrial culture's historical memory in only three generations, given the culture has been successfully erased physically.

- It is a given that the survivors/refugees had a pact of secrecy; an intention to hide their past, but the erasure must be complete enough that no militant "Knights Templar" sort of society is required to maintain it.
- Would prefer to rely on the Mandela Effect to replace the memories. This allows for a small percentage of people to "know the truth" but be written off as crazy conspiracy theorists by the general population. IOW, one or two "enlightened" individuals can fit in the solution.

Can this be done in three generations? If not, what needs to happen for full erasure?

---

† A living record is any record known in living memory; an account held by a credible person who is alive.

Comment: On one hand, they *"have vast (and legitimate) archives of the old civilization"*. On the other hand, *"have absolutely no living memory of the former society"*. Unless the word "living" is to be taken in the sense that nobody alive has a memory of the former society (which is obviously true after 130 years), these two requirements are contradictory.

Comment: How so? Ancient Egypt is in this situation today. We have their hieroglyphs and the Rosetta Stone to know *of* them and how they lived, but no cultural identity exists. We don’t even know what race they were. I want to accomplish this in only 3 generations. It is imperative that “how the end came” remain a mystery.

Comment: "We don’t even know what race they were" - we have a fair amount of genetic data from the various slaves/priests/servants and ruling class mummies. It's not clear what you mean by race anyhow as the definition's really fuzzy. You refer to "cultural identity" - could you explain what that means in this context?

Comment: Oh, we absolutely know what "race" they were, if by "race" you mean physical anthropological type. Physically they were jusrt as they still are. And the question is about memory, not cultural identity. We know the names of lots of ancient Egyptians, we have portraits of lots of ancient Egyptians, we have their buildings, we have their stories, we know quite a bit of their history. Yes, they were less inclined to scribbling than the Greeks and the Romans, and as a consequence we don't know their daily life in as much detail. But their memory is far from being lost.

Comment: [This is how they looked like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fayum_mummy_portraits) -- the famous late-Roman-era realistic [Fayum portraits](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Fayum_mummy_portraits). (Aren't we lucky that the Romans valued life-like portraiture?)

Comment: The portraits were painted from the 1st century BCE to the 1st century CE. Roman era, as I said. Contemporaneous with the people whose likeness they show. *Nobody* painted portraits like that in the 10th century. Middle Ages and so on. And your bizarre idea that we don't know whether they were black or white is bizarre. They were typical north-African Europoids, just like the people of northern Africa are nowadays. The gist of the text you linked is a gentle post-modernist rehashing of the old observation that "race" as we use the word today did not exist in the Antiquity.

Comment: Ah, and when they say that the images derive more from Greco-Roman artistic traditions they mean exactly that. Not the subjects depicted; the painting style and technique. (And they are wrong. It's pure *Roman* tradition, not Greco-Roman.) The Romans, as we are thankful for that, despised the Greek style of idealized portraits and preferred portraits true to life. With warts and all, eyes too wide apart, asymmetric traits etc. Thanks to Roman style and technique we have good likenesses of very many people. some important, some ordinary, who lived in the late Antiquity.

Comment: @AlexP I wouldn’t trust Wikipedia in a matter like this anyway but you are claiming that the debate over the race of ancient Egypt was settled 900 years before it began. OK. I don’t accept that. How did they study their subjects’ complexion? (they were mummies!)

Comment: *Complexion?* You do know, of course, that Europoids have a *very* wide variety of skin tones? From quite dark in northern Africa and Arabia to almost no pigmentation at all in Sweden? (It may be a cultural difference. For example, in your culture, do Persians and Afghans count as "white" or "Caucasian" or "Europoid" or whatever name is used? If not, what "race" would they be?) (P.S. Cultural detail: in traditional, pre-Hellenistic, ancient Egyptian paintings, the convention was to show women in a lighter brown color, men in a darker brown color. Go figure.)

Comment: @AlexP In any case it doesn't relate to the problem, it is a given they are descendants. What is lost is a void in history only 130 years ago. The civilization was lost (assumed destroyed), no record was made, and the survivors have grown into a new one, but not one person alive can point to a relation in that past. Genealogy did not survive, no "war stories" or "pandemic accounts" made it. *Some* people can forget their great-grandma (or never know them), but an entire civilization?

Comment: OK, so are you then referring to the *oral tradition*? You're asking if it's possible that no oral tradition has been passed down? Is that right?

Comment: Have you read George Orwell's 1984? Manipulating history is a central theme of the book. The protagonist works for the ministry in charge of it. So it gives a good insight into the techniques used by that society.

Comment: @AngryMuppet that would be at least one component, yes, along with written histories in any irrefutable form.

Comment: Could someone please leave a hint as to what is missing? I thought it was extremely specific, down to 130 years/3 generations/no physical evidence/etc., etc. I'm having a tough time guessing what's missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened already more than once in Polynesia. Tribes just vanished because the only survivors were commoners children who basically knew little to start with and were busy trying to survive. So a single generation and a single event was enough.

Their kids only knew vague horror stories by the second generation, by the third it's just some stuff that happened long ago.

It doesn't even need a genocidal event but takes longer. Knowledge gets lost really quickly if it's superceded by something else. Polynesian 'culture' these days is mostly christianity over a thin remembrance of ancient times. Unrecognisable in the most part to anyone from ancient times. In one generation the language was not allowed to be used, religion, clothing and moral systems were enforced and by the second everyone thought that was how it had always been.

Chatham Islands is a good example. They lost 95% of the population including all their elders to a genocide by Maori with New Zealand assistance. They obviously had a rich culture but no one understands their artifacts anymore.

Comment: That's partially incorrect about the Chathams; the 95% genocide still left survivors like the Solomon family, who transmitted their memories down.

Comment: @SeanOConnor who transmitted some vague memories down. They weren't from the elites, those all died, and it's the elites who hold the cultural knowledge. We have tribes like that all over polynesia, a few peasants survived and generations later we have ghost stories of not much value.

Comment: I think this answer combined with the others satisfies the requirement. This major crisis would lead to the 1984-ish police state @SeanOConnor needs, at least briefly; and the Amarna period was successfully erased (but rediscovered). It may take 5-6 gens to completely erase history, but in 3 gens, the "few who knew" would be regarded as the lunatic fringe, society would likely write them off until concrete evidence backed them up. Such evidence is simply impossible in my scenario. Erasure is *fait accompli*.

Comment: I like that, the few who know are just 'conspiracy theorists'

Answer (score 2):

## The Secret Will Last as Long as they Remember to Forget:

The problem is that without a police state, there will always be people who ask the question: "Hey, what happened?"

Humans are painfully curious, and while the first generation may have been perfect in their behavior, the second generation will either need to be in on the secret (and thus all entrusted with the knowledge of the truth without the compelling evidence of why it's so important to forget) or vigorously told to ignore inconsistencies because there are things that must not be discussed. I have teenagers, and I can't imagine either one going along with that.

The Egyptians wanted to forget the Amarna period when the pharaoh went rogue and dismantled the faith he was the living embodiment of. They were certain that all signs of the heresy were gone. But the smashed remains of the Amarna temples were used as fill in the walls of the rebuilt temples. Ironically, the remains of the engravings were protected from wear.

They either need to know there is a secret that must be kept (preventing it from truly being a secret) or they must forget (leaving human curiosity unchecked about tiny bits of information that don't line up). So as long as they remember to forget, they still remember. Once they forget, nothing will stop someone from figuring it out one way or another.

Comment: It actually sounds like the Amarna historical revision worked had then not retained the physical remnants of it. My scenario has no physical remains whatsoever, as the circumstances of the story proide.

Answer (score 2):

## Rich people make this impossible.

Rich people like to have collections of rare things, and have the ability to ignore social rules. They would likely collect rare things from the past, and records, and ignore social rules of morality.

## Underground things make this impossible.

The world is much too vast to dig up every inch in just 130 years. Numerous buildings and items and such would be buried. Hidden outposts would be lost under plantgrowth.

All this means that later people would still keep discovering new stuff later. We have extensive archeology efforts irl, and still keep finding new old stuff.

Comment: It is a given in the question that all remnants of the civilization “have been successfully erased,” and the story would make the things you describe impossible anyway. One can not dig up a relic without first travelling to it, and that distance is part of what is hidden; it cannot happen. They are left with a virtual modern US Library of Congress, but nothing more of their past.

Comment: @VogonPoet The Library of Congress has every published book; you'd get the culture almost in its entirety, complete with sheet music, screenplays, etc. You mean a subsection thereof, right?

Comment: Well only the written portion thereof. The means to record video was not available. So, yes. Nearly all cultural, political, historical, and scientific records are known, ending abruptly and inexplicably 130 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

No, because 3 generations is still within living memory.

It seems any society short of 1984 could not prevent the transmission of information directly from grandparent to grandchild, or indirectly via the intermediate generation 100.0% successfully.

That's before accidental books, journals, postcards, computers, etc, get found.

You'd need 100.0% commitment from every member of both generation 1 and 2, which isn't possible even due to mental health, let alone the inevitable ideological disagreements and personal reasons for remembering things (title deeds, genealogy, church history, etc).

Maybe 6 generations? Or 5? 3 is not enough.